# How to compile .tex file to a pdf using luajittex engine?

Tags: luatex, texlive

I have recently found that modern TeX Live 2014 distribution has new LuaTeX engine `luajittex`. As far as I know this is just experimental however if we consider that `luatex` is beta version, almost everything about LuaTeX is still experimental. I compile my documents with `lualatex` using TeXstudio editor and it uses `luatex` engine by default, the compilation command line in Windows is:

`lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`

Up to now the `lualatex` works perfectly and reliably for all my documents (usually I compile tex files to pdf).

I know that some people have reported  that the `luajittex` has faster compilation time comparing to `luatex`. I would like to try new luajittex engine but I could not find any information how to change the default compilation engine.

What is a compilation command line if I want to use the `luajittex` engine in typical TeX-to-Pdf scenario?

Comment: `luajittex --fmt=lualatex test.tex` works for me in the sense that there is a resulting PDF. My installation keeps on regenerating the format file, I don't know why.

Comment: @topskip Thank you for your comment. I tried to compile the sample document but at the first attempt I got no pdf and the following message at the end of log: I can't find the format file `lualatex.fmt' but that was problem from my side with zero-length sample file, **then after fixing the problem, the 2nd attempt was successful** and I got the PDF file!

Comment: The problem I mentioned in my previous comment was not related to zero-length sample file. It seems that is the problem with TeX paths because the first attempt I did under Windows 7, and the second one - under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @topskip: The default setting in TL15 disables the luajitlatex format in fmtutil.cnf, but you can enable it e.g. by creating a local fmtutil.cnf see http://www.preining.info/blog/2015/04/tex-live-the-new-multi-fmtutil/. Worked fine for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I am observing the same behaviour - each compilation with `luajittex`, it is regenerating the format file. How to stop it? I use TL2014 frozen.

Comment: Find your fmtutil.cnf with `kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf`. Open it and enable the luajitlatex format by removing the `#! `. Then create the format with `fmtutil-sys --byfmt luajitlatex`.  Then you should be able to use `luajitlatex test`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you very much for your detailed instruction. I have a partial success. After completion of all of those commands, now I can compile a document with `luajittex --fmt=luajitlatex test.tex` command line so that the process is normal and no regeneration of format. However `luajitlatex` command is not found and I could not find any binary or script with such name, so I cannot do `luajitlatex test` right now.

Comment: @VladimirS.: add a link from luajittex to luajitlatex

Comment: It seems I'm missing `luajitlatex` in my Fedora repos of TL. Which version of TL started including `luajitlatex`? Sounds interesting to try it out sometime.

Comment: @polemon Linux TL distributions do not have the `luajitlatex` executable script by default. I have created myself something like  `exec luajittex --fmt=luajitlatex "$@"` in bash script placed in TL binary path and made it executable.