# How to avoid input stack overflow during recursion

Tags: tex-core, expansion, recursion

Although there is already a [↗question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372639/trying-to-eliminate-stack-overflow-during-recursion) with a similar title, I take the risk of asking again, because the linked topic is a bit bloated in my opinion, the answers/solutions too complicated.

So here is a more generic example:

```
\def\recursion#1\nil{%
  \ifnum#1>0
    \expandafter\recursion\the\numexpr #1-1\relax\nil%
    {#1}%
  \else%
    {Start}{0}%
  \fi%
}

\edef\result{\recursion 4997\nil} %works up to 4996

\show\result %`{Start}{0}{1}{2}{3}...'

\bye
```

It saves the result `{Start}{0}{1}{2}{3}...{<initial value>}` in `\result`. Thus, the wanted recursion macro is expected to be expandable.

With default settings of TeX Live, the code above only works for initial values up to 4996, but else fails with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`, probably due to nesting of `\ifnum...` clauses.

---

In an attempt to solve the problem, I tried to put off the recursion call behind the `\fi` as follows:

```
\def\recursion#1\nil{%
  \ifnum#1>0
    \expandafter\firstoftwo%
  \else% 
    \expandafter\secondoftwo%
  \fi%  
    {%
      \expandafter\recursion\the\numexpr #1-1\relax\nil%
      {#1}%
    }{%  
      {Start}{0}%
    }%
}
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\edef\result{\recursion 2499\nil}

\show\result %`{Start}{0}{1}{2}{3}...'

\bye
```

To my great surprise this code fails even earlier, namely for initial values greater than `2498`.

So, what is going wrong here? How can I solve the problem of stack overflow?

Comment: but the linked question has such a clear and lucid posted answer:-)

Comment: Oh my, I it was you :-) .

Comment: I guess the overflow is caused by the  tokens left behind in the input stream?

Comment: @AlexG What I said was wrong, sorry. jfbu wrote in a comment what caused the problem :)

Comment: @AlexG Still, the solution I wrote was basically constructing the sequence from the other end as david has answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a tail recursive call you need to build the result token list from the other end:

```
\def\recursion#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1>#2
   \expandafter\eatv
  \else
    {#1}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\recursion\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}%
}

\def\eatv#1#2#3#4#5{}


\edef\result{{start}\recursion{0}{7000}} %works up to 4996

\show\result %`{Start}{0}{1}{2}{3}...'

\bye
```

Comment: Once again, a clear and lucid answer :-)!

Comment: Also nice how you avoid `\nil` delimited arguments.

Comment: the great superiority of expl3 shows as it has `\use_none:nnnnn` ! `:)`

Comment: @jfbu : But I would have to `\cs_generate_variant:Nn\use_none:nnnnn{NNNnn}`, right?

Comment: @AlexG No need honestly. In your case, if you wanted to optimize more with `\exp_after:wN` and `\q_stop` you can use `\use_none_delimit_by_q_stop:w .. \q_stop` to gobble all that. I mean, if you used the delimited argument for some kind of better performance, if it was not intended, obviously grouped arguments are *more standard*.

Comment: But if you weren't looking for that exact performance `\cs_set:Npn \alexg_recursion:nn #1 #2 { \int_compare:nNnF {#1} > {#2} { {#1} \alexg_recursion:on { \int_use:N \__int_eval:w #1 + 1 \__int_eval_end: } { #2 } } }` defining the variant `:on`.

Comment: But wouldn't this again suffer stack overflow, looks similar to what I already have.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking slovenly: During recursion don't let your tokens go directly into the input-stack as the input-stack is small. Instead collect them within macro-arguments as the memory for macro-arguments usually is considerably larger.

```
\def\recursion#1{\innerrecursion{#1}{}}%

\def\innerrecursion#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1>0 %
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
    {%
      \expandafter\innerrecursion
      \expandafter{%
      \number\numexpr #1-1\relax}{{#1}#2}%
    }{%  
      {Start}{0}#2%
    }%
}
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\edef\result{\recursion{5000}}

\show\result %`{Start}{0}{1}{2}{3}...'

\bye
```

Comment: By the way: The gist of my approach is the same as the gist of David Carlisle's approach: Collecting tokens within macro arguments instead of flushing the input stack directly. With my approach the list is **not** built from whatsoever "other" end.

Comment: `\the\numexpr` is faster than `\number\numexpr`.

Comment: this approach is f-expandable, however it is much slower than x-expandable code as in David's code (which however requires an `\edef` to be used, in absence of an `\expanded`  primitive) because it has a cost for TeX to fetch an argument which keeps getting longer.

Answer (score 2):

Define suitably `\alex_repeat:n`:

```
\input expl3-generic.tex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \recursion #1
 {
  {Start}{0}
  \int_step_function:nnnN { 1 } { 1 } { #1-1 } \alex_repeat:n
 }
\cs_new:Npn \alex_repeat:n #1 { {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\edef\result{\recursion{5000}}

\show\result

\bye
```